# Shell Script(bash) - Accept only positive integer or comma separated positive integers

Tags: bash, shell

I have a requirement where $1 should be only one positive integer greater than zero or a list of comma separated positive integers.

```
./xyz.sh 1
```

Or

```
./xyz.sh 1,11,124
```

Any other input - the script should exit.

`$1` - command line parameters

I have tried :

```
PARA_METERS=\`echo $1\`  
if [[  "$PARA_METERS" =~ ^([1-9]+,)*[1-9]+$ ]]; then
```

and

```
echo $1|/usr/bin/perl -0777 -ne '/^([1-9]+,)*[1-9]+$/ && print'
```

This works on command line but not inside script.

`\#!/bin/bash` is the shell I am using. I am not able to handle it in a shell script!

I could use `Python/Perl` or `sed/awk` inside the script just to check the regex and validate.

```
OS: Linux 2.6.32-358.32.3.el6.x86_64
Shell: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right lines with a regular expression, you just need to change it a bit:

```
re='^[1-9][0-9]*(,[1-9][0-9]*)*$'
[[ $1 =~ $re ]] && echo 'it works!'
```

The regular expression matches an integer with one or more digits (leading zeroes not allowed), optionally followed by any number of the same thing, preceded by a comma.

Testing it out:

```
validate () {
    re='^[1-9][0-9]*(,[1-9][0-9]*)*$'
    [[ $1 =~ $re ]] && echo 'it works!'
}

validate 1 # it works!
validate 1,11,124 # it works!
```

Comment: Many Thanks @Tom

It works perfectly!

I have added a caret at the starting of regex so that it becomes
 ^[1-9][0-9]*(,[1-9][0-9]*)* 

else it matches -10 for me if I use it without the caret.

So,

`+ [[ -10 =~ [1-9][0-9]*(,[1-9][0-9]*)* ]]` matches and control goes over to main functionality which should not be the case.

Comment: Yeah I think anchors at the start and end are important, I've added them to my answer.